# How to set the default value of remember me in the persistent login module to on?

Tags: users

The [persistent login](https://www.drupal.org/project/persistent_login) module 
gives a "Remember me" at login.

How to set this value default on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like that module offers such a setting by default, so you'll have to change the option using hook_form_alter as well (in a custom module).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // I don't check for the specific form here, since we do have a specific element we can look for.
  if (isset($form['persistent_login'])) {
    $form['persistent_login']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
  }
  if (isset($form['account']['persistent_login'])) {
    $form['account']['persistent_login']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

You will have to make sure that your custom module is run **after** the persistent login module:

- [How to update a module's weight](https://www.drupal.org/node/110238)
- [There's a module for that](https://www.drupal.org/project/modules_weight)

Comment: Made my first custom module..module is working. weight of this module is 1, from persistent login is on zero. The hook is not working.     The details of the form are: 
<form class="user-info-from-cookie" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user/register" method="post" id="user-register-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input id="edit-persistent-login" name="persistent_login" value="1" class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox">
So I change the code to: 
  if (isset($form['user-register-form'])) {
    $form['edit-persistent-login']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
        
  }   But it is not working.

Comment: you should not have to change the $form['persistent_login'] part, I took that from the module itself, so it should be present, did you change the function name to YOURMODULENAME_form_alter()?

Comment: if you enable devel module you could do a dpm($form); in the function as well, to see if your hook is triggered at all. can you put your .module file on pastebin.com?

Comment: "Andre, here the link http://pastebin.com/djZCWhrW

Comment: Put dpm($form); in the code. Nothing happens, so the code is not executed..

Comment: did you enable whayme module? please pastebin the .info file as well

Comment: also clear the cache.

Comment: Did not give every role dev permissions. I can now see dpm() on the page for every form. Seeing every form twice in kromo. I don't understand the array. Dump of the module file is at http://pastebin.com/tqhQFRK0. Did a dump with dvr. This can be found at http://pastebin.com/FraQYUmN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22469/discussion-between-andre-b-and-justme).